# Pass objects in ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

I need to pass objects in ajax request in order to "PUT" files or data to my rest service. How can i do it? Thank you.

## update

i have this code:

```
var invoice = {};
invoice.POSWorkstationID = "POS7";
invoice.POSClerkID = "admin";
invoice.CustomerName = "Alice in Wonderland Tours";
invoice.IsFreightOverwrite = true;
```

should i do this:

```
parameter = "{BillToCode:"+invoice.CustomerName+",POSWorkstationID:"+invoice.POSWorkstationID+",POSClerkID:"+invoice.POSClerkID+",IsFreightOverwrite:"+invoice.IsFrieghtOverwrite+"}";
```

and this:

```
data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you can use jquery to do this may be like this:

```
$.ajax(
       {
          type: "PUT",
          dataType: "json",
          data:POSTData,
          url: 'www.youurlhere.com/path',
          complete: function(xhr, statusText)
          {
              switch(xhr.status)
              {
                 //here handle the response
              }
          }
       });
```

POSTData is the data in json format that u supply to the rest, you can turn an object into a json format by simply pushing the attributes but respecting JSON Format syntax

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jQuery post http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
you have few options there:

```
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to communicate client and server side is (IMHO) JSON.
You could serialize your object into json format, with this lightweight library => 
http://www.json.org/js.html 
Look for **stringify** method.